# setting the first responder view of the table but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have **UITableViewController**. In this controller I add a subview UIView with UITextField in it. When the UITextField get first responder got

> setting the first responder view of the table but we don't know its
>   type (cell/header/footer)

Code as below:

```
@interface UserAlbumListViewController (){
    NSString *newAlbumName;
    UITextField *albumNameField;
}

@end

-(void)addAlbumButtonPressed:(id)sender{
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
UIView *opaqueView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
opaqueView.tag = 1001;
opaqueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];


UIView *controllerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
controllerView.tag = 1002;
controllerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
controllerView.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 60.0f, frame.size.width - 20.0f, 90.0f);
[opaqueView addSubview:controllerView];

albumNameField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
albumNameField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect; 
albumNameField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Album Name",nil);
albumNameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
albumNameField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
albumNameField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
albumNameField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
albumNameField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
albumNameField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
albumNameField.text = @"";
albumNameField.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f , 10.0f, controllerView.frame.size.width - 20.0f, 30.0f);
[albumNameField becomeFirstResponder];
[controllerView addSubview:albumNameField];


UIButton *_cancelButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
_cancelButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[_cancelButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake( controllerView.frame.size.width - 90.0f,  albumNameField.frame.origin.y + albumNameField.frame.size.height + 10.0f, 80.0f, 30.0f);

[_cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(opaqueViewCancelButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[controllerView addSubview:_cancelButton];

UIButton *_OKButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
_OKButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[_OKButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_OKButton.frame = CGRectMake( _cancelButton.frame.origin.x - 90.f, _cancelButton.frame.origin.y, 80.0f, 30.0f);
[_OKButton addTarget:self action:@selector(opaqueViewOKButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[controllerView addSubview:_OKButton];

[self.view addSubview:opaqueView];

[controllerView release];
[opaqueView release];
}
```

How to avoid this warning?

Comment: Can you show us where you declare `albumNameField`?

Comment: I tried declare in `@interface UserAlbumListViewController : UITableViewController{}` got same warning

Comment: I am unable to recreate your problem, but I would suggest that there is some other issue at work here as in your code it is **not** possible for the `albumNameField` to become first responder. The [UIResponder docs](http://bit.ly/Lm4WIE) state that you should only call `becomeFirstResponder` if the view "is part of a view hierarchy". This means you need to add it as a subview **before** you try to make it the first responder. Check the `BOOL` return value of `becomeFirstResponder` to see if he method call was successful to see what I mean.

Comment: @Barjavel the `albumNameField` does becomes the first responder. I removed `[albumNameField becomeFirstResponder];`. Tap UITextField to get focus, but the waining still there. Actually I don't think the problem is from text filed, from the warning message, I think it because `opaqueView` is not part of tableview. But I don't want to believe that we cannot add a sub uiview to a UITableViewController

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The warning is telling you that you added opaqueView to the table view directly. Table views expect interactive subviews to be added to tableHeaderView, tableFooterView, or within a cell.

The offending line is `[self.view addSubview:opaqueView];` because self.view is the table view.

You can fix this is one of several ways. If you are using a navigation controller, you can push a new controller with opaqueView in it. You can pop up a modal view over the table view with opaqueView in it. You can change the structure such that self.view is not a table view (which is a lot of work).

---

***UPDATE***

This answer is kind of busy, so I will post an update. I discovered that Apple uses a different solution then the ones I suggested.

Instead of `[self.view addSubview:opaqueView];` which tries to add the subview to a table view, you can  do `[self.view.window addSubview:opaqueView];` which adds the subview directly to the table view's window. You need to keep in mind that you are using a view so the bounds and frame may be different than `self.view`.

Comment: can this become the reason for crash it will be nice if some one answer this.... thnx in advance

Comment: Is there some way I can hide this warning message?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The only solution is to not call `-[UITableView addSubview:]`

Comment: I got the same error message adding a search bar with a search display controller to an existing table view controller's XIB. I find the IBActions for the search bar and search display delegates being correctly called so not yet sure if the message points to something that will bite me somewhere down the line!

Answer (score 1):

I got this "(cell/header/footer)" error when a view pushed to the NavigationController was an instance of UITableView instead of UIView. Then in the the Xib editor for the class, I added a view to the canvas, and then text was ultimately added to the view through a couple more views down. The UI Builder will let you specify UITableView as the superclass of the view and place a view on the canvas, even though adding items to this view then caused the message "setting the first responder view of the table but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)".

Comment: ... other people searching for ways to fix the message may may find this answer helpful.