# What does this warning mean: "setting the first responder view of the collection view but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)"

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, ios6, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a UITextView in each cell. When I tap on one of the text views and the keyboard comes up, I get this warning in the output panel:

`setting the first responder view of the collection view but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)`

Text input works fine, though. However, I'd really like to know what this warning means before I use this code in production.

Comment: How did you add the `UITextView` to the cell?

Comment: Any luck on getting what it means? I have the same problem with a UISearchBar and my UICollectionView steals firstReponder on reloadData (outputting this warning).

Comment: No, I can only guess that it has some meaning to the Apple devs and they accidentally left it in the code.

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm afraid there is something wrong, bks after the warning occurred, we can't do insert/delete operation to the UICollectionView!

Comment: given the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764804/setting-the-first-responder-view-of-the-table-but-we-dont-know-its-type-cell-h?rq=1 which has the same warning but with table, and its answer, i would assume there is something wrong with the way you add subviews to the collectionView. Either that or something to do with the selection handling code. Could you update with a sample/proof of concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple, "you can safely ignore that".

https://devforums.apple.com/message/717898#717898

Comment: I can't find the information in this link..can you explain me in detail

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to explain. The original poster had the error and Apple responded in the first comment that it is safe to ignore.