# How can I fix this warning: setting the first responder view of the collection view but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)?

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I'm trying to adding search bar to my collection view. What I want to implement is filtering data using `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText` method.

Everything worked fine when I used table view. In table view, when I added `UISearchBar` using `addSubView` method, I got the almost same warning, but it disappeared when I added `UISearchBar` using `setTableHeaderView` method.

But in collection view, the method which performs same as table view doesn't exist. So I added `UISearchBar` to supplementary header view, like below:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableView;
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        reusableView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [reusableView addSubview:self.searchBar];
    }
    return reusableView;
}
```

When I added `UISearchBar` object by this way, I get the warning, "setting the first responder view of the collection view but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)?" every time I tap the search bar.

It seemed to work fine except the warning, but I get into the problem when I type something. If I type one letter, the keyboard input view goes down, so I have to tap the search bar again to keep searching. If the word I want to search is 5 letter word, I have to tap the search bar 4 times. It is awful.

I think this occurs because of the warning. I googled with the warning context, and I found the only article on stackoverflow related to this.
(other articles are related with table view. All of them seems to be fixed by using `setTableHeaderView`.)

The article is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821670/what-does-this-warning-mean-setting-the-first-responder-view-of-the-collection).

But I don't registered iOS developer program, so I can't read that article. Is there anybody willing to help me with this?,

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the header view is reloaded when "reloadData" is called on the collectionview, thus the searchbar looses it's first responder status.  The only workaround I could find is to keep a BOOL of when an active search is going on and if it is, then set the searchbar to firstResponder in the collectionviews "cellForItemAtIndexPath":

```
if(activeSearch && ![searchBar isFirstResponder])
{
    [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is  happening  because reloadData will also reloading the header.
```

> i.e. your old header is removed from the collection view, queued and 
>   reused at the time of your dataSource implementation

don't worry about this warning. you can ignore this warning

Comment: Then how can I fix the problem that if I type one letter, the keyboard input automatically goes down? When I added search bar directly to the view, that problem didn't occur but in that way I can't use layout what I want to...

Comment: Based on your answer, I guess the problem occurs because of reloadData in textDidChange. I guess when I type a letter, the header view contains search bar dequeued and queued, so the keyboard input goes down...

Comment: Is there any other way to include search bar in collection view, so that the search bar goes up and finally hides as I scroll down?

Comment: There might be a way around this, but so far I haven't looked into this

Comment: I solved the problem [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540291/how-to-reload-only-data-section-of-uicollectionview). I found that there is just one difference between this way and setting the `tableHeaderView`, which is that the scroll bar goes behind the search bar.