# How to add ChildViewController to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Due to design Constraints I have to add an UiViewController to UITableViewController through

```
[controller addChildViewController:self];//self = uiviewcontroller controller = Instance of UITableViewController

[controller.view addSubview:self.view];
```

It adds it with a bit lag, but I get a warning in my console

"setting the first responder view of the table but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)"

I guess it is because controller.view is tableview and not normal uiview, it throws this error both in iOS6 and iOS7

How can I add a ChildViewController to UITableViewController?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to? What do you need to do that cannot be accomplished with header, footer, and content cells? If you really need to, would a custom UIView work instead of a UIViewController?

Comment: Any view you add as a subview of a table view controller is added to the table itself, so that's why you're getting that error -- the table view doesn't know how to deal with your child's view.

Comment: I just tried what you did here (albeit from the table view controller's perspective) and did not receive any warning.

Comment: Also, it looks like this warning would occur if you have a textfield in any subview within a tableview that isn't a header, footer or cell. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10766933/84783

Comment: yes @rob5408 I have added a childviewcontroller with textfield, like you have in twitter app when press the button for new tweet

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Don't. UITableViewControllers can't really contain anything else but a table view. As rob says in his answer, it's better to have a parent view controller that has a container view with your table view controller in it, plus anything else you need, and perhaps other child view controllers if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Your quickest fix for the layout you're looking for is to have a parent view controller that includes both your table view controller and the child view controller with the UITextField.

Or just a view controller with a UITableView (with it's data source and delegate set to your view controller) and your child view controller added.